# Loading UserDetails by username and password in spring security?

Tags: spring-security

I'm pretty new to Spring Security and have run into a problem, hope someone here help:

DaoAuthenticationProvider retrieves a user by username ONLY (when you implement UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(String username), but my problem is that our password is hashed on the DB by a DB function, meaning if I retrieve by username, it wouldn't match with the supplied password since what I get from the DB is a hashed version.

How do I go about implementing a solution on Spring Security where I can match both a username and password on the DB side before I retrieve the User object and mark a user as authenticated?

Something like UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password) is what I'm looking for.

I have a feeling I'll have to cook up my own custom implemenation since I read somewhere that Spring Security never sends the password to the DB. If I do, can someone please point me to the right direction on how to get started?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may write a UserDetailsServiceImpl extends `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`

override the `loadbyusername()` method. Read user from db.. Your user will have a hashed password..

On login screen, doAuthenticate user as `login(username, hash(password))`..

they will match..